# MVC Razor Modelbinding for partial view (post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, binding

For a postrequest the model binding does not seem to work, if I'm using a partial view.

The main view's model is MainViewModel.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ModelPart Model {get;set;}
}

public class ModelPart
{
    Public string MyVariable {get; set;}
}
```

If I pass the main viewmodel to the partial view, then the binding is successfull and any input in `MyVariable` is found in the Controller Post method.

MainPage

```
@model TEST.MainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Views/Shared/_Input.cshtml", Model.Model)
}
```

Partial

```
@model TEST.ModelPart

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyVariable)
```

This works!

If I pass only the ModelPart to the partial view, then the binding is not successful.

MainPage

```
@model TEST.MainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Views/Shared/_Input.cshtml", Model)
}
```

Partial

```
@model MainViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model.MyVariable)
```

This does not work. As I would like to use partials to re-use input forms, this issue is something I would like to resolve.
Do I have to do a manual bind of the properties in the partial view? Another workaround is to pass values using javascript, but is there anyway I can get the default binding to pick this up?

Answer (score 0):

When using @Html.Partial , the names generated won't be prefixed by the the parents. Thus while posting the model binder won't be able to map post object.

There are 2 workaround :

- Manually set the prefix of the context while rendering partial view (not a good idea).
- Use editor templates (better alternative).

Editor templates are used the same way as partial view, but they will bind correctly.
To do so:

Main view:

```
@model TEST.MainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m)
}
```

Editor template  (in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MainViewModel.cshtml )

```
 @model MainViewModel
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model.MyVariable)
```

Comment: That's more or less what I do in my second example and it requires that I have the same "MainViewModel" in the Template. I would like to use the partial without restriction to MainViewModel. It should only use "ModelPart"

Comment: Then create an editor template for the ModelPart only:

`@model TEST.MainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Model)
}`

And 
`@model ModelPart
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyVariable)`